# Rename USB stick appends nA to name

Tags: usb-drive, rename

I try to rename a usb stick (i.e. give it a new label). Both using gparted and mlabel I get following behaviour: The rename works, but the string "nA" is appended to the name (it is less than 11 characters). This is very annoying, because the appended string is right-justified, and spaces are inserted in the middle between my name and the "nA", resulting in a new label like "new-name nA".

Anyone have an idea how to get rid of the "nA"?

**Update**: This behaviour only takes place with new names that are at least 8 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug in mtools](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mtools/+bug/887446) and a patch was offered earlier this month.

The bug entry mentions a partial workaround (pad it out with underscores until you hit the label length limit and the nA is pushed off the end).

Another I have is to add a space to the end of your desired label (eg. `"DOCUMENTS "`). Then you get `" A"` rather than `"nA"`, which can then often be made to look intentional.

Comment: Yes, bug report and patch are from me; I forgot to add that information here..

Comment: Ahh. That'll teach me to write answers when I'm too tired to read names.